# when pressing the share button, "Share via" menu appear only after 4 seconds

Tags: android, performance, share

When I press the share button in my app the "Shave via" menu appear after 4 seconds. When I do the same action from the Gallery app or Whatsapp it appears in half of a second. I'm guessing that is not related to my old smartphone because in other places it works very fast. What am I missing?

This is the code:

```
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory("Action")
                    .setAction("Share photo")
                    .build());
            Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageView);
            if (bmpUri != null) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(EditView.getText(), EditView.getText());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to upload a photo first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debugger to find out which line of code is taking so long?
Have you tried it without getLocalBitmapUri()
Have you tried it without ClipboardManager or ClipData ?

Comment: I have tried without ClipboardManager or ClipData but not without getLocalBitmapUri(). I will check it now with the debugger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is going to be `getLocalBitmapUri`I have seen this function elsewhere and it does a lot of work on the main thread such as loading an image, compressing the image and then saving the image onto the phones storage. Dependent upon the file size this may take some time.

If this is by design then you could show a ProgressDialog like so

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Please wait whilst we load your image", true);
```

Then dismiss the dialog with

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

just before you call:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: When i'm thinking about this now, i'm not sure why I really need "getLocalBitmapUri". All I want is to share my imageview to another apps. Is there a way to share imageview without "getLocalBitmapUri" ?